# Numerically Solving 2nd Order System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

This is equations of motion in $3D:$ How can we numerically solve this system of the equations? (preferably Euler). can you give a sample of $2$ step sizes how is it possible?

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -vk_d\frac{dx}{dt} + vk_l\frac{dy}{dt}$ 
$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = -vk_d\frac{dy}{dt} - vk_l\frac{dx}{dt}$ 
$\frac{d^2z}{dt^2} = -vk_d\frac{dz}{dt} - g$

$v = \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2 +(\frac{dz}{dt})^2}$

$g, k_d, k_l$ are constants.
step size = $0.01$ sec = $t$

Intial Conditions:
x,y,z = 0 
$\frac{dx}{dt}=10.45$ 
$\frac{dy}{dt}=5.45$ 
$\frac{dz}{dt}=33.45$ 
$v_0=25$

Comment: Giving constants is useless if you do not give all constants, $g,k_d,k_l$ are missing. It should also be $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$. What is the second force, some kind of Coriolis force? But then it is proportional to the square of the speed over ground,...

Comment: Yeah you are right , my bad, it should velocities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python (and similar in other languages) you would encode the ODE function of the right side, for the first order system with $v_x=\dot x$ etc., as

```
def motioneqns(t,u):
    x,y,z,vx,vy,vz = u
    v = (vx**2+vy**2+vz**2)**0.5
    ax = -kd*v*vx + kl*v*vy
    ay = -kd*v*vy - kl*v*vx
    az = -kd*v*vz - g
    return vx,vy,vz,ax,ay,az
```

and pass it along to any general-purpose solver, which might be one implementing the Euler method, or RK4, or some higher order method with adaptive step size.

If you use implementations similar to those in [Does fourth-order Runge-Kutta have an higher accuracy than the second-order one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238995/does-fourth-order-runge-kutta) you need to wrap the result list in a vector type, for instance `numpy.array`, either in the return line or in the function call. For further inspiration on getting the trajectories as list see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333687/how-do-i-solve-a-2nd-order-differential-equation-for-projectile-motion, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645649/cannot-get-rk4-to-solve-for-position-of-orbiting-body.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it was helpful. But I wanted to write theoretically / Mathematically.

Comment: You mean like writing $u_{n+1,k}=u_{n,k}+hf_k(t_n,u_n)$, where $u_n=(u_{n,1},...,u_{n,d})$ is the state vector at time $t_n$?

Comment: yes, I want the working for 2 steps (step-size=0.01 so for 0.01 and 0.02) using Euler. i cant seem to wrap my head around the mathematics