# What does the order of a numerical method represent?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

I heard that Heun method was second-order Runge-Kutta method (RK2). Why "second-order" ?

Comment: Why can't I accept an answer ?

Comment: You need to wait for 15 minutes

Comment: Practical demonstration: [steps, function evaluations and errors for Euler, Heun, RK3, RK4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238995/does-fourth-order-runge-kutta-have-an-higher-accuracy-than-the-second-order-one/1239002#1239002)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Second order" means that when the step size is devided by 2, the error is devided by 4.